# What is the second "to" in "to take this opportunity to foreground poetry"?

Tags: infinitives, syntactic-analysis, particles

> That’s why it’s particularly appropriate for us to take this opportunity **to** foreground poetry as an aural experience.
>   — [Source](http://goo.gl/Kgvmah)

Is this "to" the same as "something to say?"

P.S.: Isn't this presumptuous? It's like we have the right and legitimacy to do this!

Comment: There's nothing unusual about that preposition. Just try to parse the sentence without prejudice and you will see it's a normal sentence like any other.

Comment: My judgment aside, it simply means "It's appropriate that we do this?"

Comment: It's "an **opportunity** to do (something)".

Answer (score 7, accepted):

*To* is a particle which often precedes the plain form of the verb when it is functioning as an infinitive. It can no more be omitted before the verb *foreground* in this sentence than it can be omitted before *take*.

If you think the sentence is presumptuous, then that is up to you. It is not a matter of grammar.

Comment: What's that down vote for?

Comment: +1 After reading the question, I was just as confused as the reader... until I considered "foreground" to be a verb.  Barrie's answer confirmed my suspicions.  Shame on the downvoter.

Comment: Will the site explode when Barrie reaches 100k?

Comment: @EdwinAshworth: obviously so, and Barrie wins. My worry is what will happen to the English language.

Comment: Somebody should start writing a B100 000 bug fix.

Answer (score 0):

[Many if not all nouns take complements](http://aclweb.org/anthology//W/W08/W08-1602.pdf) of one form or another.

Some nouns (whether appearing in the subject or object) take to-infinitive clauses as complements:

> Their claim to have found the answer is outrageous.
>
> His decision to go home was wise.
>
> He made a wise decision to go home.
>
> Their plan to open a shop sounds good.
>
> They have a great plan to open a shop.
>
> Her intention to do voluntary work is admirable.
>
> The failure to sign Messi was pivotal.
>
> The offer to provide cheaper accommodation is welcome.

Notice that all these nouns (there may be exceptions) have associated verb-forms (decide / plan / intend / fail / offer . . .) that catenate with to-infinitives (he decided to go home; I think that was wise.

In fact, OP's example is an exception, as 'opportunity' has no corresponding verb; the structure is identical to the other examples, however:

> [We should] take this / [We have a great] opportunity to foreground [this type of
>   literature].

Comment: The OED has an entry for the the verb _opportune_, but I wouldn't recommend it.

Comment: I thought it was the best we had. (I'm under the influence of Christmas-cracker humour).